# what if we dont want any data type in template/generics

Tags: c++, generics

when we use generic data-types from `STL` or our own implemented generic classes, **do we have the option of specifying no data type...???**

example :

if i am making a graph library....some person using that library may want to store some data in the nodes and some person might be only intrested in the connections between the nodes....

so to provide a generic library we put some data variable say

```
template <class T>
class Graph
{
    T data[number_of_nodes]; // This somehow corresponds to data stored in each node
    Edge e[number_of_edges];
}
```

No if i dont want any data variable at all what should i do...?

Comment: Maybe you specialize the entire class for `void`

Comment: but the user may want to store some thing greater than the size of void while using it...how to over come that problem..?

Comment: So does you user want to store data or not?

Comment: that depends on the user...he may or he may not...

Comment: My template skills are lacking, but shouldn't the user descend from node? Then she can specify associated data (or not) as needed.

Comment: So it's not the same: as Dieter suggested, the one who doesn't need to store data use the `void` specialisation, and the other one uses the generic implementation instantiated to whichever type he wishes to store

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: No, that's a Java-ism. C++ has full-blown templates; it can create the derived classes automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let me wrap your plain array in a class, you can have an explicit specialization for void and pay only one extra byte:

```
template<int N, class T>
class array {
    T v[N];
    const T &operator[](int i) const { return v[i]; }
    T &operator[](int i) { return v[i]; }
};

template<int N>
class array<N,void> {
    const void operator[](int &i) const {  }
    void operator[](int &i) { }
};

int main()
    cout<<sizeof(array<100,int>)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(array<100,void>)<<endl;
}
```

You could also have an specialization for your Graph class instead, but I think specializing only the array wrapper is less work.

Anyway, the best idea seems to be making Node a generic type in Graph, provide a base Node implementation without extra data, and let the user define its own derived node type, as suggested by "500 - Internal Server Error", unless you don't need to store anything else at all about the node in your Graph.

Comment: You don't even need that one byte overhead. Google "Empty Base Class Optimization" how to avoid it.